# iPhone - how to generalise my 3 projects with same UI's but different data??

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

i'm developing 3 projects for iPhone with same user interfaces and options the only difference between all the 3 projects is only my images and database will be different.
Is there any easy way to generalize these, i mean instead of creating 3 different projects is there any easy way to reuse the 1st one with slight modification??

any help is appreciated in advance,thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create targets for each of your "sub projects" and then change their "Copy Bundle Resources" in to only include the files you need. When you build each specific target, only those files will be bundled.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating static libraries having common UI elements

then You can import the library n your project, for additional objects/view, you can extend the classes in your static library.

Answer (score 0):

you could try making it so the images and databases come from a xml .... and so all you have to change in your project is the adress to parse. I know it's not that helpfull but it is a idea if you have the resources to do it.